# Feasibility of running an ML model on phone hardware?

Tags: android, ios, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I've trained a TensorFlow model which takes my RTX2080 several seconds per action (in addition to 20-30 seconds to initialise the model).

I've been looking into turning this into an iOS/Android app running on tensorflow lite, but apart from the technical challenge of converting the model into a tensorflow lite model and everything else,

I am wondering about the feasibility of this running on phone hardware  even on a reasonably modern phone with inbuilt GPU would this still likely be too slow for practical purposes?

Can anyone who has built an iOS/Android app with tensorflow lite where the phone is responsible for computation comment on performance and other practical considerations?

The only other option of having requests served by my own server(s) on AWS, for example, would turn into a major expense if the app had significant use.

Comment: I'm not sure without more details as to what problem/model you are trying to solve/run inference on device that anyone can assist. You could at least look at existing tensorflow lite samples (image classification, text classification) to get an idea of what is feasible.

Comment: On the device, are you talking about simply performing inferences using a previously trained model? Or about training a model on the device? When you say it’s taking “several seconds per action” on your RTX2080, again, was that training or inference?

Answer (score 0):

I have created an image recognition app in swift using TensorFlow lite and did not find any performance issues with it. The prediction took anywhere from 3 - 5 seconds consistently , which I personally think is not that bad.So I would suggest to go ahead with your app using TF Model.Thanks!